# ImageMagick for macOS as Universal Libraries

Tags: macos, imagemagick, arm64, apple-silicon

In order to build my app as an universal app (ARM64 & x86_64) on macOS 13.4 I have to first build the ImageMagick libraries as universal libraries. I've already installed all dependencies as universal libs with MacPorts.

There is the flag *--enable-osx-universal-binary* that I use when launching *configure* but it seems a reminiscence from the PowerPC days and fails to create the config, with this error:

> configure: error: cannot make gcc report undeclared builtins

Can ImageMagick be compiled as universal libraries (ARM64 & x86_64)?

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found was to compile ImageMagick 7 separately on both architectures (ARM64 and x86_64), then use the *lipo* command to combine the dylibs.

```
lipo -create -output IM-Universal/libMagick++-7.Q8.5.dylib IM-x64/libMagick++-7.Q8.5.dylib IM-ARM64/libMagick++-7.Q8.5.dylib

lipo -create -output IM-Universal/libMagickCore-7.Q8.10.dylib IM-x64/libMagickCore-7.Q8.10.dylib IM-ARM64/libMagickCore-7.Q8.10.dylib

lipo -create -output IM-Universal/libMagickWand-7.Q8.10.dylib IM-x64/libMagickWand-7.Q8.10.dylib IM-ARM64/libMagickWand-7.Q8.10.dylib
```

Comment: Usage of `lipo` for the same purpose is also discussed (briefly) here: https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/discussions/5472